How much support does a ground offensive in Lebanon have among the Israeli public?
Israeli forces and Hezbollah have been trading blows across the border for months now. The Israeli government appears to be under some political pressure to gain the upper hand and ensure the return of the displaced Israelis; as a gov't spokespersons put it: the current state of affairs is "not a sustainable reality". There's been some talk of an impending Israeli ground offensive as well, possibly with the purpose of occupying a security/buffer zone in Lebanon etc.
I'm curious how much public support these proposals have in Israel. Are there any polls on these matters, i.e. ground offensive and/or occupying a buffer zone in Lebanon?

Are the "displaced Israelis" a different group from the ones who were taken prisoner by Hamas? Are they people who have moved because of the fighting with Lebanon?

@Obie2.0 #2 - see https://apnews.com/article/israel-lebanon-hezbollah-evacuees-gaza-war-1841834d89af938a8445821567640aea  : 60k evacuees in Israel. Two wrongs don't make a right and expecting a peaceful border from Lebanon is not unreasonable from Israel.  Lebanon being a near-failed state doesn't really change that.

One should not confuse modern democracy with the dictatorship of majority, as it used to be in Athens. A democratic government is simply obliged to defend the rights of minorities - like the displaced population here.

With the usual disclaimers that polling data is notoriously unstable, subject to sampling biases, and easily manipulated by the surveyors if they so desire, there are two datapoints which suggest a majority of Israelis would support military action in Lebanon for the purpose of cowing Hezbollah.
In December of 2023, relatively soon after the October 7th attacks that prompted Israel's current military options in Gaza, 51% of Israelis believed a military strike against Hezbollah to impair their fighting ability was worth the risk of opening a 2nd front to the war.  This evidence comes from the Viterbi Center for Public Opinion and Policy Research at the Israel Democracy Institute - the IDI is a non-partisan think tank and seems to have a reasonable reputation for doing good public opinion research.  The timing of that poll, however, is important to note.  It's relatively proximal to the October attacks and is also much earlier the in war against Hamas.  War fatigue can be swift in how it erodes enthusiasm for military action.
The second piece is far more recent (February 2024) poll published by Maariv, an Israeli newspaper with limited circulation and conflicting assessments as to its political leaning. I can't easily locate the poll itself, but it is widely reported, including in reporting from the BBC as showing 71% of Israelis supporting a military operation in Lebanon in response to increased rocket attacks, etc.
The IDI polling is likely of higher quality, but the Maariv polling is more recent which is important when a shooting war is going on.

It may be a stretch to claim the first poll truly indicates a majority.  The poll concluded 50.9% in favour, but also states: "605 men and women were interviewed
in Hebrew and 151 in Arabic, constituting a representative national sample of the entire adult population of Israel aged 18 and older. The maximum sampling error for the entire sample was 3.55%± at a confidence level of 95%."  See https://en.idi.org.il/media/22474/israeli_voice_index_data_2312_eng.pdf

@EndAntisemiticHate I agree it's a stretch, but that's still the point estimate given by the survey and so insofar as it goes, it's evidence in support of the proposition.  Indeed, I include it specifically as a partial counter-point in the manner you suggest, because IDI also shows good discipline in polling, etc.  Whereas the more sensational, recent result has other reasons to suspect it.
My preamble to this answer is meant to point out that while the technical answer to 'is there survey data' is yes, there's a lot of wiggle room when it comes to interpreting that data.

I would feel that February is still relatively "ages ago" in terms of measuring war fatigue as suggested in William Walker III's answer. During that time Israel's allies have become far less supportive and the ceasefire arrangements to return hostages have become seemingly more tenable (though all of these traits can only be measured subjectively).
Many citizens would likely be starting to reflect on what conditions would be considered a "victory" in their minds, and perhaps even starting to reflect on who they want leading the nation. In fairness it must be stated though that any polls about the current Israeli government's popularity are probably as variable as those about war support.
From the anecdotal perspective of a casual observer (me) it would seem that the appetite for continued warfare has largely diminished in the current context. Opening a second (or even third in Iran's case) front with few hostages yet to be returned and lacking international support would be a difficult proposition to sell to the public I imagine.
TLDR; it seems there is very little in reliable metrics to judge the support for a Lebanese front in Israel.

I concur that February is also 'ages ago' in war time.  I'm honestly surprised that I couldn't find anything more recent, this feels like a topic that would be receiving rapid-cycle testing, especially by opposition parties looking for a moment to make electoral gains.
